# VNC to a server that requires ProxyJump param in .ssh config

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

I have ssh access to a certain server that I would like to access via remote desktop using Remmina. The server isn't on my local network, so I need the following line in my `.ssh/config` in order to ssh to it:

```
ProxyJump my-user@our.local.network.name
```

I have the server set up in Remmina this way:

```
Name: foo
Protocol: VNC - VNC Viewer
Server: [its IP address]
User name: my-user
Password: my-pass
Enable SSH Tunnel: True
Custom: my-user@our.local.network.name
SSH Authentication: Password
```

The result of trying to connect this way is that I'm prompted for my password, and then refused access with this error:

```
SSH password authentication failed: Access denied.
Authentication that can continue: publickey, password
```

Can anyone advise whether Remmina can support ProxyJump the way ssh can, and if so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

- set "Pre Command" in remmina to `ssh -vNL 12345:[its IP address]:5900 my-user@our.local.network.name`
- set "Server" in remmina as `localhost:12345`
- leave "SSH tunnel" unticked in remmina

---

You can have as complicated jumps as you want this way. When I'm using regular ssh, I connect to an internal ip `192.168.1.42` through a jump host `bastion` which connects to `domain`. I have this in my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host bastion
     HostName bastion.example.com

Host domain
     HostName domain.example.com
     ProxyJump bastion

Host internal
     HostName 192.168.1.42
     ProxyJump domain
     # Needs to go via `domain` since bastion is on a completely separate network
```

With this config, I can just `ssh internal`, but of course remmina doesn't understand that. If there wasn't a need for going through `bastion`, I could use put `domain:22` in the "SSH tunnel" settings, but now I need to go through both.

So instead, we open up a tunnel from `localhost:12345` to the RDP/VNC port 5900 on `internal` via `domain`:

```
ssh -vNL 12345:129.242.131.140:5900 domain
```

You can try that in a terminal, then from another one do `telnet localhost 12345` – if the ports are right, you should see

```
$ telnet localhost 12345
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
RFB 003.889
```

(hit ctrl+] and ctrl+d to exit). If that didn't work, you may have to try another port than 5900 (I think for several displays, it'll use 5901, 5902 etc.)

Now just put `ssh -vNL 12345:129.242.131.140:5900 domain` into remmina's "Pre Command", and use `localhost:12345` as the server, and untick "SSH Tunnel".